# Django model's clean method multiple error

Tags: python, django

I have been playing around with my test project

I have this clean method in my model

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    f1 = models.IntegerField()
    f2 = models.IntegerField()

    def clean(self):
        if self.f1 > self.f2:
            raise ValidationError({'f1': ['Should be greater than f1',]})
        if self.f2 == 100:
            raise ValidationError({'f2': ['That's too much',]})
```

I don't really know how to raise both errors and show it in the admin page because even if the two `if` is `True`, only the first `if` error is shown(obviously) how do I show both errors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could build a `dict` of errors and raise a ValidationError when you are done (if necessary):

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    f1 = models.IntegerField()
    f2 = models.IntegerField()

    def clean(self):
        error_dict = {}
        if self.f1 > self.f2:
             error_dict['f1'] = ValidationError("Should be greater than f1")  # this should probably belong to f2 as well
        if self.f2 == 100:
             error_dict['f2'] = ValidationError("That's too much")
        if error_dict:
             raise ValidationError(error_dict)
```

Comment: [Link to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) that recommends this, "If you detect errors in multiple fields during Model.clean(), you can also pass a dictionary mapping field names to errors" (Note that the dict values are validation errors)

Comment: Link to the above quote for the docs of newer version of Django (1.9 docs no longer available): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if you have to raise multiple errors on one field (say because a related field is erroneous), you will override your first error message.

Answer (score 0):

I would expand the accepted answer by setting a classmethod like this:

```
@classmethod
def add_error(cls, errordict, error):
    for key, value in error.items():
        if key in errordict:
            if isinstance(errordict[key], str) or isinstance(errordict[key], ValidationError):
                errordict.update({key: [errordict[key], value]})
            elif isinstance(errordict[key], list):
                errordict[key].append(value)
        else:
            errordict.update(error)
    return errordict
```

That way, if a key already exists in your error dict, it will be casted in a list. That way, all the errors will be raised, even if there are multiple errors per field.

```
adderror(error_dict, {'field', 'error message'})
```