# How to validate multiple fields in model clean method in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-validation

In my Django model I am using `clean()` method to validate two sets of fields' values. I am housing both the conditions in the same `clean()` method. However I find that the first condition is checked by the system and the second one is ignored.

Here is my model and the fields:

```
class Rates(models.Model):
    master_doc = models.ForeignKey(Origin, ...
    exit_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True, default=0.00)
    from_date = models.DateField(null=True, verbose_name='From date')
    to_date = models.DateField(null=True, verbose_name='To date')

    def clean(self):
        if self.exit_rate <= 0:
            raise ValidationError({'exit_rate': _('The exit rate must be more than 0.')})
        if self.from_date is not None:
            if (self.to_date == self.from_date):
                raise ValidationError({'to_date': _('From Date and end date may not be the same.')})
```

In this instant case, a validation error is raised only for the first i.e. field `exit_rate`. If I reverse the order of the **check**, a validation error is raised for the date fields alone, and not the rate field.

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35963896/12379095) and used `error_dict` but getting error `'ValidationError' object has no attribute 'error_list'`

**How do I ensure that validation error is raised in case either of the conditions is not met?**

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to test all the conditions first, and then raise one exception containing the multiple messages. Something like

```
def clean(self):
    errors={}
    if self.exit_rate <= 0:
        errors['exit_rate']= _('The exit rate must be more than 0.')
    if self.from_date is not None:
        if (self.to_date == self.from_date):
            errors['to_date'] = _('From Date and end date may not be the same.')
    if errors:
        raise ValidationError(errors)
```

I can't immediately find a reference to the exact form of `raise ValidationError( things)` to pass multiple errors. The above is a guess based on the obvious extension of the raise statement in the original question.

Comment: Your answer is absolute on mark. I had tried the same based on the linked question. Where I was going wrong was **to have this** `error_dict['to_date'] = ValidationError({'to_date': _('From Date and end date may not be same.')})` **instead of** `error_dict['to_date'] = _('From Date and end date may not be same.'). If you check the linked post, you may be able to see the reason. However, many thanks for help!!

Comment: On a second thought, the validation is failing on **Update**. And funnily enough, in create it worked perfectly. It's the same model, same view and everything. Any particular reason why I may expect this?